# stripe - can not use same payment-method for new paymentIntents

Tags: javascript, python, stripe-payments

I have the issue that saved 3d-secure cards can not be re-used again.

it says, card number invalid. below is the paymentmethod created. (sorry, it is in german).

[image]

in this picture, you see, it says "For future usage" and shows the paymentintent id.

if I want to use the saved card for new payment this way: 
[image]

it says, card is invalid.

I have some more codes, so dont know which part is relevant. i will paste js part already here:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: card,
    billing_details: {},
  },
  return_url: 'https://localhost:8000/'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.error) {
    showError(data.error.message);
  } else if (data.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
    orderComplete(clientSecret);
  }
});
```

Comment: In Stripe, a Payment method is always single use. If you want to reuse the payment method, you will have to attach it to the customer first. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach and then create/confirm a payment_intent with the customer + payment_method

Comment: @wsw I already do it in backend. I think, I know why: 
I retrieve the payment methods of the user and show in frontend. User selects previously saved card and hits on "pay". then code goes to confirmCardPayment but the card element is empty, because user is selecting another radio button, instead of filling new #card-element. do you have any idea how to solve this? :/